# Setting Topic log retention in confluent-kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I could not find in the documentation how to set the retention time when creating a producer using confluent-kafka.

If I just specify 'bootstrap-servers' the default retention time is 1 day. I would like to be able to change that.

(I want to do this in the python API not on the command line.)

Answer (score 4):

Retention time is set when you create a topic, not on the producer configuration.

If your `server.properties` allows for auto-topic creation, then you will get the defaults set in there.

Otherwise, you can use the [AdminClient API](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/v0.11.5/examples/adminapi.py#L30-L48) to send a `NewTopic` request which supports a `config` attribute of `dict<str,str>`

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic

# a = AdminClient(...) 

topics = list()
t = NewTopic(topic, num_partitions=3, replication_factor=1, config={'log.retention.hours': '168'})
topics.append(t)

# Call create_topics to asynchronously create topics, a dict
# of <topic,future> is returned.
fs = a.create_topics(topics)

# Wait for operation to finish.
# Timeouts are preferably controlled by passing request_timeout=15.0
# to the create_topics() call.
# All futures will finish at the same time.
for topic, f in fs.items():
    try:
        f.result()  # The result itself is None
        print("Topic {} created".format(topic))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to create topic {}: {}".format(topic, e))
```

In the same link, you can find an alter topic request

Comment: I know shouldn't post thank you messages but this answer was super helpful

Comment: It says NewTopic has no keyword argument named config. Can you please help. Ty!

Comment: @Dhiraj I'm not sure about any updates, but the class is documented from the github repo

Comment: From what I can see, the `config` argument is no longer supported.
https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/kafka/admin/client.html#KafkaAdminClient.create_topics

Comment: @rodo This answer is for the Confluent Python library

Answer (score 0):

the retention time is not a property of the producer.
The default retention time is set in broker configfile *server.properties* and properties like *log.retention.hours*, e.g. /etc/kafka/server.properties ...depending on your installation.

You can alter the retention time on a per topic base via e.g.

```
$ <path-to-kafka>/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper-quorum> --alter --topic <topic-name> --config retention.ms=<your-desired-retention-in-ms>
```

HTH....

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do this from a program? Do I really need to use a system call (say in python) to call the shell script?

Comment: Added answer for doing this from Python